# How to install libX11-dev on mac os x sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, dlib

I am working on facial landmarks and therefore I have installed dlib on my mac. When I try to execute a program in Xcode from learnopencv.com, the compiler says:

```
error "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code. Turn DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT off if you want to use it."
error "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
```

I already installed XQuartz. I don't know what to do anymore. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suffered from this error for 3 days and finally fixed with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`